# Couldn't connect to server apollo.modulusmongo.net

Tags: mongodb, modulus.io

I'm trying to connect MongoDB database on modulus.io by referencing [this][1] tutorial.

I've registered with modules .io and received the database url. (*Modulus provides the database URL you need and you can use mongoose.connect to connect to it*)

i.e.

```
MONGO URI
mongodb://<user>:<pass>@apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/wIp4otyd
MONGO CONSOLE
mongo apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/wIp4otyd -u <user> -p <pass>
```

But when I'm trying to connect it through both node.js and console its showing me following error:

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongo apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/wIp4otyd -u <my_uname> -p <my_pwd>
2016-02-04T12:01:07.097+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/wIp4otyd
2016-02-04T12:01:09.455+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 52.6.181.208:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target ma
chine actively refused it.
2016-02-04T12:01:09.457+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Its connecting to local perfectly (`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');`)
but refusing to modulus.io (`mongoose.connect('mongodb://<my_uname>:<my_pwd>@apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/wIp4otyd');`)

Comment: Looks like the port is closed. Double check that the server configuration has it open. Otherwise, you might need to contact them.

Comment: @Qix: Port is not closed. I received same from `modulus.io`

Comment: `27017/tcp open  unknown` it says it's open. Check your connection string again.

Comment: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://<unm>:<pwd>@apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/wIp4otyd');` is it correct?